# Jin chess pieces, how to obtain higher resolution?

Tags: pieces

There are a set of good chess piece graphics at: https://code.google.com/p/raptor-chess-interface/wiki/AdditionalChessSets. In particular, I'm interested in the graphics used by the Jin Chess client, e.g.: JinAlpha.

[image]
[image]

Unfortunately, the highest resolution is at 132x132, which is too little in the 2015 standards. I'm looking for something like 256x256, or even SVG (resolution independent).

Anybody has any idea where to get the source for the graphics (e.g.: Adobe files)? Who created those graphics? Is there any way to increase the resolution without image loss? Who would have the skills to enhance the graphics?

Free or paid solutions are welcome.

Comment: To pay for the work (with copyright violations possible...), try Amazon's "Mechanical Turk".

Comment: @TonyEnnis I could do that, but if I know where to get the original photoshop sources or who created those graphics, I could do it myself or contact the author.

Comment: Yep. That would be easiest.

Comment: Did you contact the author at http://www.jinchess.com/contribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this link to Github which could be useful: https://github.com/lukasmonk/lucaschess/tree/master/Pieces/JinAlpha

They seem to have the pieces in SVG format.